# Can Entity Framework Reverse Engineer Code First be used with MySql?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, entity-framework

I'm working with MS Visual Studio 2012 Update 1 on Win 7 Ultimate SP1 and [EF Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d).

I am trying to use the Reverse Engineer Code First functionality of entity framework on a MySql DB.  I can successfully connect to the DB, but when it tries to complete the code gen I get the following errors:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.DbContextPackage.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.InstallPackage(Project project, String packageId)
   at Microsoft.DbContextPackage.Handlers.ReverseEngineerCodeFirstHandler.ReverseEngineerCodeFirst(Project project)

One or more errors occurred while processing template 'Entity.tt'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes\EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude(1,4) : error : A processor named 'T4VSHost' could not be found for the directive named 'CleanupBehavior'. The transformation will not be run.  The following Exception was thrown:
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot find processor for directive 'T4VSHost'.
   at Microsoft.DbContextPackage.Utilities.EfTextTemplateHost.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.ITextTemplatingEngineHost.ResolveDirectiveProcessor(String processorName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Engine.ProcessCustomDirectives(ITextTemplatingEngineHost host, TemplateProcessingSession session, IEnumerable`1 directivesToBeProcessed)
```

I have been unable to find any information using my google foo.

Comment: Most likely, but it depends on your package installed.  IS this you?  http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d name: Justin Skiles

Comment: Yes, that is the package I'm using.  I'll update the question with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently an **Active** bug with entity framework.  The bug details can be seen [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/769934/entityframework-bug-in-vs2012-update-1-ctp).

There are currently 2 work-arounds and the one that I used is below.

Open the File for C#:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes\EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude
```

or for VB.net:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes\EF.Utility.VB.ttinclude
```

And Remove the First Line:

```
<#@ CleanupBehavior Processor="T4VSHost" CleanupAfterProcessingTemplate="true" #>
```